# The onclick function works when inside an inline script but not in external js file due to window.onload = function(). Require workaround

Tags: javascript, html, animation, canvas

Due to window.onload = function(){} in the external js file the onclick for stop does not work. I am trying to stop an animation.
The code which works in an internal js file is
                    var stop = setInterval(animate,60);
                    function stop() {
                    clearInterval(stop);
                    } 
If I write the code outside of window.onload then it cannot reference the animate function which is within.
The html file is given below as also the external js file.

```
<!doctype HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Cable Car</title>
        <meta name="Description" content="Using Canvas">
        <meta name="robots" content="noindex">
        <!-- This is a HTML Comment -->
        <!-- Below is the HTML Shim that uses a conditional comment -->
        <!--[if lt IE 9]> <script src="dist/html5shiv.js"></script><![endif]-->
        <script src="scripts/stackoverflow.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <style>
        .leftBar {
        width: 15%;
        height: 80%;
        float: left;
        }
        .middleBar {
        width: 60%;
        height: 80%;
        float: left;
        margin: 20px;
        }
        </style>
</head>
<body>
        <header role="banner">
            <h1>Canvas and animation</h1>
            <hr>
        </header>
        <aside role="complementary" class="leftBar">
            <button id="stop" onclick="stop()" >Stop</button>
            <p>Stop the animation</p>
        </aside>
        <main>
        <article class="middleBar">
            <canvas id="canvas" width="650" height="350"></canvas>
        </article>
        </main>

<footer role="contentinfo">
<hr>
<p><small>
Copyright &copy;2016. All rights reserved</small>
</p>
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Below is the external js file

```
window.onload = function(){         
            var cnv = document.getElementById('canvas');
            var ctx = cnv.getContext('2d');

            //the image object being created and loaded
            var pict = new Image();
            pict.src = "images/cablecar23.png";
            pict.onload = function(){
            ctx.drawImage(pict,0,-10,pict.width*0.25,pict.height*0.25);
            }

            //the moving image
            x = 0;
            y = -17;
            /*this change  variable determines how far the car moves in a redraw and direction */                       
            change = 2;
            //width and height are dimensions of the box
            w = 650;
            h = 100;

            function animate() {
                    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);
                    ctx.drawImage(pict, x, y,pict.width*0.25, pict.height*0.25);
                    //checking cable car position
                    if(x >=630) { 
                    //if thecar is on extreme right then it exits the screen
                        change = 0; 
                    }
                    //update horizontal position
                    x = x + change;
            }
                    //cause function to repeat with milliseconds
                    //calling the animate function to start the cable car
                    var stop = setInterval(animate,60);
                    //below function is not referenced
                    function stop(){
                    clearInterval(stop);
                    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the name of variable `stop` so it isn't the same name as function

Declare both outside `onload`

```
 var intervalStop; 
 function stop(){
      clearInterval(intervalStop);
 }
```

Inside onload  change

```
 var stop = setInterval(animate,60);
```

To

```
 intervalStop = setInterval(animate,60);
```

You wouldn't have any of this problem if you were to get away from using inline script and use [unobtrusive event listeners](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)

Comment: Thanks for the promptness in answering. I have done exactly as suggested. However, the stop is still not working, though there is no console error. No errors at all.

Comment: Create a demo that reproduces the problem...in a sandbox like jsfiddle.net, plunker, codepen etc

Comment: Here is my jsfiddle. I have changed the image to a red ball otherwise the remaining code remains exactly the same with your suggestion incorporated. https://jsfiddle.net/spkl/6cctu18n/2/

Comment: Because you redeclared a new `var` inside `onload`. Remove `var` so it is the same variable. https://jsfiddle.net/6cctu18n/3/

Comment: Was my mistake in the answer ... i apologize